# InvalidOperationException: Could not parse value will return next time I'm in Vegas. in line 130, column Label

Tags: c#, ml.net

I'm learning how to use ML.Net, I have researched and tried to learn Neural Networking using c#. I found ML.Net on the web and thought about using this tech and taking advantage to learn.

I have this program in console app .net core 6.0:

```
        using Microsoft.ML.Data;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace BinaryClassiferSDCALogisticsRegression_Proj1
    {
        internal class SentimentInputData
        {
            [LoadColumn(0)]
            public string SentimentText;

            [LoadColumn(1), ColumnName("Label")]
            public bool Sentiment;
        }
    }

        using Microsoft.ML.Data;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace BinaryClassiferSDCALogisticsRegression_Proj1
    {
        internal class SentimentPredictionOuput : SentimentInputData
        {
            [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
            public bool Prediction;

            public float Probability;

            public float Score;
        }
    }
```

And this is my program:

```
        // See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
    using BinaryClassiferSDCALogisticsRegression_Proj1;
    using Microsoft.ML;
    using Microsoft.ML.Data;
    using static Microsoft.ML.DataOperationsCatalog;

    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");


    string _trainingDataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "yelp_labelled.csv");
    string _modelPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Model.zip");

    void classifySentiment()
    {
        MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

        IDataView trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<SentimentInputData>(_trainingDataPath, hasHeader: false, separatorChar: ',');

        TrainTestData trainTestData = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(trainingDataView, testFraction: 0.2);

        var dataPreperationPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(outputColumnName: "Features", inputColumnName: nameof(SentimentInputData.SentimentText));
        var sdcaLogisticRegressionTrainer = dataPreperationPipeline.Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.SdcaLogisticRegression(labelColumnName: "Label", featureColumnName: "Features"));
        var model = sdcaLogisticRegressionTrainer.Fit(trainTestData.TrainSet);
        IDataView preditctionsForEvalutingDataView = model.Transform(trainTestData.TrainSet);
        CalibratedBinaryClassificationMetrics metric = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Evaluate(preditctionsForEvalutingDataView);

        var t = "";
        Console.ReadLine();


    }


    classifySentiment();
```

I'm getting an error on line:

```
var model = sdcaLogisticRegressionTrainer.Fit(trainTestData.TrainSet);
```

There is a CSV file that I downloaded here, where I think the error is referring too.

```
https://github.com/amazingTest/amazing-AI/blob/master/src/sentiment_classification/english/data/sentiment%20labelled%20sentences/yelp_labelled.csv
```

the error is:

```
InvalidOperationException: Could not parse value will return next time I'm in Vegas. in line 130, column Label
```

Comment: i dont think the file has been formatted properly, not sure

Comment: the csv file has extra commas in the text

Answer (score 0):

I found another resource here:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gopilingam1/datasets/main/yelp_labelled.txt


IDataView trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<SentimentInputData>(_trainingDataPath, hasHeader: false);
```

And i got the metrics back.

It was the csv file that had extra commas in the text.